# How to add extra info in a PHP HTML email when submitted in HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, html-email

I've been researching as much as I can about PHP and just haven't come across the info I'm looking for or maybe I have and I just haven't understood PHP enough to tell that it was the answer I needed. The website I'm building the company deals with copiers.

In my HTML form I've made it so that a customer can input their copier number and say the number of copies that machine has and it all sends using PHP email, but in HTML format. The thing is though they want to be able to add an extra machine and number of copies which I have working in the HTML page and Javascript. The added information does not want to send in the email though and that's were my problem begins.

Here is an example of my html code:

```
<form id="formexample" action="example.php" method="POST">
  <div id="add-machine">

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="control-label" for="equipment">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <label class="control-label" for="equipment">Equip. ID#:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipment" id="equipment" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
       <label for="meter" class="control-label">Total No. of Copies: </label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meter" />
      </div>
    </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="extraMachines" id="extraMachines" value="" />

  <button type="button" id="click">Add Machine</button>

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Now for the example of the PHP I'm using:

```
<?
$email = $_POST['email'];
$equipment = $_POST['equipment'];
$meter = $_POST['meter'];

if(empty($equipment) || empty($meter) || empty($email) || !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){   
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
    }
    else{
        // create email body and send it    
        $to = "example@domain.com"; // ----->>> put your email to receive mails
        $email_subject = "New Copier Total Submitted";
        $email_body = "
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>New Copier Total Submitted</title>
        </head>

        <body>
         <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' id='backgroundTable' align='center' style='background-color: #f7f7f7; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#e4e4e4; width: auto'>
            <tr>
             <td>
              <table class='Responsive' cellpadding='15' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size:12px; width: 650px'>
                <tr>
                 <td style='font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, Serif; font-size:15px;'>
                  <h3 style='text-align: center; text-decoration:underline'>Here are the details:</h3>
                  <p>Email: $email_address</p>
                  <p>Equip ID#: $equipment</p>
                  <p>Total of Copies: $meter</p>         
                 </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </body>
        </html>";

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        $headers .= "From: example@domain.com";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email"; 
        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  }
?>
```

Not adding the Javascript unless needed but I can tell you with "add machine" button I used a Jquery append method to add on the extra inputs for the added machines and total counters. Also using a Javascript jqBootstrapValidator for appending a fail or success message. So any information on that is also helpful.

I'm hoping someone will be able to help and if there is any other information need about my code just ask and I'll update it when possible. Note that I have no PHP code in my HTML. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please rethink your question title. What good is it to know your level of expertise? Simply summarize the nature of the question.

Comment: `or maybe I have and I just haven't understood PHP enough to tell that it was the answer I needed` This happens ALOT for people in all walks of web design, it's good you realise this is a possibility.

Comment: In your HTML, `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="meter" />` is missing a `name` attribute.  In PHP, not sure what `empty($)` is checking (forgot to add variable name?). Also in PHP, it looks like you're not trying to get the data for `$_POST['extraMachines']`.  You should do a `var_dump($_POST);` on submission to see all of the values submitted to begin debugging your form.

Comment: Just as a note: you can submit arrays of data in your form for PHP to handle if you have multiple fields that have the same name attribute in HTML like `name="machines[]"`.  Then in PHP you can do `$_POST['machines']` and it will return the whole list for you.  The benefit of this is you don't need an extra field for "extra machines", you can just have a list of "machines[]" and get all the values at the same time.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Thanks for the input I'll look at using the array and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Running on the assumption that your Javascript will add a new machine, with iterated numeration `machine_1`, `machine_2` etc.

This can be easily caught in PHP side of things with POSTed Arrays, as mentioned by Wounded Steven Jones:

> You can submit arrays of data for PHP to handle if you use the name attribute in HTML like `name="machines[]"`. Then in PHP you can do `$_POST['machines']` and it will return the whole <strike>list</strike> *array* for you. The benefit of this is you don't need an extra field for "extra machines", you can just have a list of "machines[]" and get all the values at the same time.

This pretty much sums it up.

I can't see your Javascript but if you have

```
<input type='text' name='machine[]' value='machine 1'>
<input type='text' name='machine[]' value='machine 2'>
```

in your HTML, submitted by form to your PHP, then your PHP will receive this:

```
$_POST['machine'] ==> array([0] => "machine 1", [1] => "machine 2")
```

And you can walk through this array of machines using `foreach`, such as:

```
foreach($_POST['machine'] as $machine){
    print "this is machine ".$machine."!<BR>";
}
unset($machine);
```

which will output something like:

> ```
> this is machine machine 1!
> this is machine machine 2!
> ```

And the point is that this process will work perfectly for any number of machines, even zero.

Comment: When using the foreach in what order would it be placed in the php file? Or does it matter?

Comment: foreach will typically cycle from `0` to `max-1` as it will be a numeric array, and the way the HTML builds the array will be that the first element on the page is value 0 and later elements will have higher values. There are plenty of PHP [functions for sorting and reordering arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) if you need the results in a certain order. @KFuller